# Apache Zeppelin vs Apache Superset

Tags: solr, data-visualization, apache-zeppelin, apache-superset

Both Apache Zeppelin and Apache Superset are able to generate queries from different datasources like Mysql, Postgres, Apache Solr, Apache Druid, etc. Can someone explain the main difference in these so that I can chose the best one for my project as per my needs.

Comment: I took a stab at answering this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67179622/zeppelin-over-superset